# Code execution after __halt_compiler

Tags: php, symfony

Next time in my life i see some bytecode after function __halt_compiler. In this case it's symfony installer. How to do that ? How to generate code which will be executable after __halt_compiler ?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you mean https://symfony.com/installer, a [PHAR](http://php.net/phar) archive that starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Generated by Box.
 *
 * @link https://github.com/herrera-io/php-box/
 */
if (class_exists('Phar')) {
Phar::mapPhar('default.phar');
require 'phar://' . __FILE__ . '/symfony';
}
__HALT_COMPILER(); ?>
```

Conceptually speaking, PHAR archives are not too different from self-extracting ZIP files (in fact ZIP is among the supported internal formats). The archive [contains](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.ingredients.php):

- A [stub](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.stub.php), which is the short PHP script you can see.
- A manifest with a description of the archive contentes
- An archive with the contents themselves
- An optional signature

The stub on top is a regular PHP script so the PHAR archive can run with the regular PHP interpreter rather than requiring a dedicated executable:

```
php foo.phar
```

This script block ends with [__HALT_COMPILER();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) to::

1. Prevent the rest of the file from being parsed and possibly executed as PHP code (the main script does all that's needed for the initial phase).
2. Populate the `__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__` constant so the PHAR library can easily detect where archived data starts.

This scripts does three things:

1. Detect whether the Phar library is available in the computer.
2. Load current file as Phar archive and register the manifest with the content description.
3. Execute the [symfony script](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/blob/master/symfony) inside the archive, which is the actual installer code.